# Problemas al mostrar la hora desde MySQL a Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql

Hola buenos dias tengo un problema al mostrar la hora de mysql a netbeans, cuando inserto la fecha y hora actual me sale bien por ejemplo 2020-08-31 13:05:55 pero al mostrarlo en Netbeans me sale la hora restada 5 horas, como solucionarlo?

mi codigo es:

```
Date date = new Date(resultado.getTimestamp(8).getTime());
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            registros[7]=df.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema con la zona horaria ya sea de tu computador o de la base de datos o del JVM puedes manejarlo desde el codigo poniendo la zona hoaria de tu pais en la fecha

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5"));
    System.out.print(df.format(date));
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html